# Adding images to alertdialog options

Tags: android, image, android-alertdialog

I need to add images to the alertdialog options. I read some tutorials but all of them are using ViewGroup class to do the job. The problem is that I can't use it, ... I think version 2.2 doesn't have it.

So... what can I do to fix it? Another method to add images? Why Is so hard adding a simple image to the alert dialog option? I have seen a lot of apps using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a layout and inflate it with LayoutInflater somehow like this: http://eventuallyconsistent.net/tag/layoutinflater/